# How to calculate with characters in C

Tags: c

Sorry if the title is not clear about what I want to achieve.
So let me explain:

I'm trying to make a calculator that can enable the use of variables that are each labeled with a lowercase letter. All lowercase letters should be usable (a-z, each with value storage). The following should be possible:
Assignment of a value in a variable, example: a = 1

Use of a variable in an invoice with direct output, example: 3 + a

Assignment of an invoice result into a variable, examples: b = 3 + 1 or c = 6 * b

For clarification again, for example the following inputs should be possible:

x=3 // Variable x receives value 3

d=9 // Variable d gets value 9

3*5 // Output result

h=9/3 // Variable h gets value Result of calculation 9/3

x * h // Output result of calculation x*h, because x=3 and h=3, output 9

i=d/x // variable i gets value from calculation, so 9/3, output result 3

I'm not looking for code snipets per se but more for a way to apprehend the problem.
Thank you in advance for any help!
This is what I did so far:

```
int main(void) {

  int weiter = 1;
  do {
    char eingabe[21];
    int zahl1 = 0;
    int zahl2 = 0;
    int ergebnis = 0;
    char op = ' ';
    int retval = 0;

    retval = scanf("%s", &eingabe);
    printf("retval = %d\n", retval);
    printf("eingabe[0] = %c\n", eingabe[0]);

    // fall2  zahl opo char
    char *peingabe = &(eingabe[0]);
    printf("peingabe = %c\n", *peingabe);

    char *temp = strpbrk(peingabe, "+-*/=");
    op = *temp;
    printf("Op = %c\n", op);
    
    temp = strtok(peingabe, "+-*/");
    printf("1.temp = %s\n", temp);
    zahl1 = atoi(temp);
    printf("Zahl_1 = %d\n", zahl1);
    temp = strtok(NULL, "+-*/");
    printf("2.temp = %s\n", temp);
    zahl2 = atoi(temp);
    printf("Zahl_2 = %d\n", zahl2);

    // fall3  char gleich zahl
    // fall4  char op zahl
    // fall5  char op char
    // fall6  char=zahl op zahl
    // fall7  char=char op zahl
    // fall8  char=zahl op char
    // fall9  char=char op char
    // fall10 char gleich char

    switch (op) {
    case '+':
      ergebnis = zahl1 + zahl2;
      printf("Sum = %d\n", ergebnis);
      break;
    case '-':
      ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;
      printf("Sum = %d\n", ergebnis);
      break;
    case '*':
      ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;
      printf("Sum = %d\n", ergebnis);
      break;
    case '/':
      ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2;
      printf("Sum = %d\n", ergebnis);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Error\n");
      weiter = 0;
      break;
    }
  } while (weiter > 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question lacks focus. I suggest you take it step by step. Can you map a variable name to a storage location (typically an array element)? Can you parse and execute `x` as well as `x=1`?

Comment: Divide and conquer: This shall be your software design principle. Before writing the first line of code, make a concept and an architecture. Then implement the very first little bit, for example reading the user's input. Then the next, for example splitting the input into tokens. And so on. Let your design reflect these separate components by using functions and modules. Do not put all in one big `main()`. -- Having said this, please [edit] your question and focus on one specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculator appears to be processing a line of text and so it will need to sample each character in order to determine how to handle it, maybe by use of a switch statement.
If you read a numerical character e.g., in the range 0 to 9, then you append or add it to a temporary storage `char` array so that you can convert it to a numerical value later.

If you detect a letter within the ASCII range a to z, then that is your variable.

Just remember to clear the temporary storage locations when no longer required.

To handle your variables, I would create an array of the largest signed values that you expect to calculate then index these based upon the ASCII value of the variable letter starting with `a` being an index of zero, `z` being 25. ASCII `a` has a value of 97, `z` has a value of `122`